# Most effective way of declaring variables for garbage collection

Tags: android

What is the most efficient way of instanciating variables for performance and memory?

this :

```
Context context = this;
Resources resources = context.getResources();
Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
ListView list = (ListView) context.findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

or this :

```
((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list)).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
```

or it doesn't matter, it is does the same so I should stick with what I like the most?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't matter. The same number of objects are created. I'd prefer the first for sake of readability. I'd skip the first line though.

Comment: I personnaly prefer the second for the code the be shorter =)

Comment: There's no right or wrong, but the first is easier to debug, and probably easier for others to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually nothing to do with garbage collection. Its about speed of execution and readability of your code. If you refer a global variable many times in a code block (between {}) you normally assign it to a local variable because accessing local variable is faster than global variable. You do the same if you have multiple calls to a method with same arguments, in this case you don't have to execute the method more than once.